# Getting blobs of an image without holes

Tags: java, openimaj

I have an image that has various blobs and I want to get only blobs that do not have holes.

I tried using `SuzukiContourProcessor.findContours` to accomplish that, but it returns `Contour`s of types `ContourType.HOLE` and `ContourType.OUTER`. Is there a way to convert a `ContourType.OUTER` to a list of `ContourType.HOLE` somehow?

Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right lines:  `findContours` returns a hierarchy of detections, so you just need to filter out the ones you don't want (i.e. looking for contours without children I'd guess). Take a look at this to see the kind of thing you can do (this goes further and looks for regions with a specific hierarchical structure - the `test` method - but you should be able to see to to modify the idea for your specific problem): https://github.com/jonhare/COMP3204/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/ac/soton/ecs/comp3204/l5/RAGDemo.java